# How to calculate slippage percent before send transaction in web3?

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py

Every time I want to check slippage, I have to send the transaction first, and if the transaction failed because of "INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT", I know that this slippage is higher than I expected, BUT I LOST FEE FOR THIS WAY, it takes fee gas and I lost money, how can I check slippage percent in web3? or does any library can help me solve this?
here is my code of simple transactions in web3 with pancakeswap smart contract.

```
...
amount_out = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(amountBNB, [spend,tokenToBuy]).call()[-1]
        min_tokens = int(amount_out * (1 - (slippage / 100)))
...
 pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
            min_tokens,
            [spend,tokenToBuy],
            sender_address,
            (int(time.time()) + 10000)
            ).buildTransaction({
            'from': sender_address,
            'value': web3.toWei(price,'ether'),
            'gas': gas_limit,
            'gasPrice': web3.toWei(gasPriceEntry.get(),'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            })
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the "'gas': gas_limit," part.

I can't remember why, but without setting the "gas" parameter you should get the same error, which you now get to see on the blockchain + you pay fees, **already while executing your code**. This way you know what the error is, but no actual transaction is being sent thus there is no gas/transaction fee for you to pay.

Next, if you intend to execute the trade nevertheless in the case if the slippage is **below your maximum slippage expectations** (e.g. below 10%) you could consider the next procedure. What if instead of "**knowing the minimum slippage and then using it**" you try to "**find the minimum slippage to work with and execute the trade**"?

Could the next procedure help you out:

- use of for loop
- default slippage is 1%, set maxSlippageAllowed (e.g. 10%)
- run for loop, on each unsuccessful trade execution (we assume because of low slippage) increase slippage for +1%
- run the loop until the trade is:
  1.) either successfully executed when hitting slippage point (break), or
  2.) the maximum slippage allowed is hit (break)

**However, remember that if you will keep the "gas" parameter in your *swapExactETHForTokens* you will be paying all gas fees for each execution through for loop!!**

Comment: Thanks for this answer! this helps me a lot, I just have one question, I'm preferred to remove ```'gas': gas_limit,``` with my initial gas_limit=500000  to ```'gas':0``` , the reason because I tried removing it and my transact still get through, at that time I thought if removing ```gas``` parameter, It would be limitless until my transact got through. am I correct?

Comment: Hm... correct, I think that then you have no gas limit set and if you sent a transaction (and slippage is OK) you could hit an unlimited gas fee, depending on the token, its source code, etc.

Why I've never dealt with such issues is the next: 
To have a good approximation of the gas fee I check one of the latest successful transactions of the same token from somebody else (as blockchain transaction log is public) and extract his gas fee value :) With the approx gas fee known you can use it in your strategy, for example, do not execute a trade if the gas fee exceeds 5$.

Comment: I got a weird problem. that is supposing that I removed the line `'gas': gas_limit,` and I got failed transaction (of course) "INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT", but how can I determine if this failed transaction because of not enough slippage or because of failure by no gas to transfer? I think this solution is not possible anymore when I have to come up with distinguishing which no way to figure out.

Comment: From my experience, I get "INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT" only if I've estimated too low slippage and I have to raise it. But I do handle the issue of having not enough funds for gas by checking the balance on my wallet. If it is lower than let us say 1$ in token then my script won't even start executing the transaction.